# Is there any way to view master details from standby server in PostgreSQL version 9.0?

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave, standby

I need some info about master server details like (master-host, master-port, etc..) from the standby server in master-slave replication in PostgreSQL **version 9.0**.

I have found a solution regarding the master details above **version 9.6**, by using the **pg_stat_wal_receiver()** view. In this [`view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-WAL-RECEIVER-VIEW), there is a column named `conninfo` which gives the info of master/primary server in a replication setup. In the same way, I need to know whether there is any possibility to find master details from the standby server in Postgres version 9.0

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------+---------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------
pid                   | 24824
status                | streaming
receive_start_lsn     | 0/E000000
receive_start_tli     | 1
received_lsn          | 0/E000060
received_tli          | 1
last_msg_send_time    | 2019-03-25 19:47:45.032121+05:30
last_msg_receipt_time | 2019-03-25 22:28:14.007002+05:30
latest_end_lsn        | 0/E000060
latest_end_time       | 2019-03-25 19:46:44.890244+05:30
slot_name             |
conninfo              | user=replication password=******** dbname=replication ho
st=172.21.166.68 port=5432 fallback_application_name=walreceiver sslmode=prefer
sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres target_session_attrs=any
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find that information using SQL. You can use tools like `lsof` on the WAL receiver process or read the `recovery.conf` file.

One thing you can try is to use `pg_read_file` on `recovery.conf`, if that function exists in 9.0, and parse the output. But that solution is fragile and ugly as hell.

Really, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

try using to read recovery.conf file with function pg_read_file

`select * from pg_read_file('recovery.conf');`